# Why cant i use two ptrs in operator overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-errors

This is annoying, i can write a function with these parameters/return, but why cant i define an operator to do this?

-edit- i am actually trying to overload `<<` the below is just for reference.

[From msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy7kx46x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
// C2803.cpp
// compile with: /c
class A{};
bool operator< (const A *left, const A *right);   // C2803
// try the following line instead
// bool operator< (const A& left, const A& right);
```

gcc error

```
error: ‘bool operator<(const A*, const A*)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

Comment: What's your actual situation for which you need that comparison?

Comment: @Kerrek: My code is using ostringstream. I now realize i need a stack and update o. I cant use reference bc references dont change. So i need a ptr. I wrote a lot of code already and would like o<<rhs to continue working. Many rhs vars are ptrs as well

Comment: Can't you write `o << *rhs` instead?

Comment: @Kerrek: There is a lot of lines written already. I dont want to break anything. I'm going to write a wrapper for o. thankfully i dont need to pass it to a func that needs an ostream

Comment: @Kerrek: I completely forgot, what happens when i want to do o<<"blah". I cant. I might as well do *o everywhere instead. But i end up writing a class to forward the << to the ostream i need with a pointer within it. It works nicely

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because every user-defined operator overload needs at least one user-defined type as a parameter. A point isn't a user-defined type.

C++03 standard, `§13.5 [over.oper] p6`:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function **and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration**.

Comment: still, pointers COULD be included in that. But they decided not to. I want to know the rational behind that. Its making my life more difficult

Comment: Eh, how could they? How would it work out for both parameters to be pointers? There are builtin operators that handle the builtin types, pointers are one of them.

Comment: AFAIK `<<` doesnt really mean anything for `T*`. And even if it does i would LIKE to overload it. operators are really functions, functions can do what i request. -edit- i mention my code use in my comment on my question

Comment: Just because an operator is not defined for builtin types, does that allow you to give them a meaning? They aren't defined for a reason, namely because shifting pointers is nonsense. If you want to know more, write a mail to Mr. Stroustrup as I won't be able to help out any further.

Answer (score 3):

Because you aren't allowed to cheat.

If you could override comparison operators for pointer types, then you would no longer be able to compare those pointers by value (aka: by the actual numerical pointer values). And that's kind of important and occasionally useful.

> My real code is actually <<. Why cant i use it for that?

For the same reason: pointers are C++-basic types. They aren't user-defined types. Do you want to be able to not left-shift pointer values anymore? OK, obviously you do, but C++ won't let you.

You can only override operators when C++ does not have existing functionality for operators with those types (with a few exceptions). C++ already has operator< and operator<< for pointers, so you're not allowed to change what they do.